# "Unmatched structure specification" in a functor definition

Tags: sml, functor

I am trying to learn using `functors` in Standard ML. I have written the following code but I keep getting an error `Error: unmatched structure specification: Element`. Can anyone please point out the error to me. I haven't been able to find it:

```
signature SET_ELEMENT =
 sig
   type element
   val equal: element -> element -> bool
 end

signature SET =
 sig
   type set
   structure Element : SET_ELEMENT

   val empty: set
   val member: Element.element -> set -> bool
 end

functor Set (Element:SET_ELEMENT) :> SET =
  struct
    type element = Element.element
    type set = element list
    val empty = [];

    fun member x [] = false
      | member x (y::ys) = Element.equal x y orelse member x ys;
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared a structure called `Element` in the signature of `SET`. Yet you did not define a structure called `Element` in the struct that is output by the functor.

Just add a line declaring it to be the same as the `Element` input to the functor:

```
functor Set (Element:SET_ELEMENT) :> SET =
  struct
    structure Element = Element
    type element = Element.element
    type set = element list
    val empty = [];

    fun member x [] = false
      | member x (y::ys) = Element.equal x y orelse member x ys;
  end
```